# In R, is there a way to know the path to the source file where a given function is defined?

Tags: unit-testing, r

I'm writing a unit test in R, which needs to read some test data defined in the same directory. But I would also like to be able to run that unit test no matter what the current working directory happens to be.

Is there a way to tell R to load a file from *here*, where *here* is defined as the directory holding the source file of the function being executed?

Comment: There is a thread in the R-Help archives that discusses this problem and offers some options: http://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@r-project.org/msg50266.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how what you mean with "I'm writing a unit test". If you just source that function from wherever, David is right and I don't even see the need to do that as you know which directory it is.

I would include that function in a package, and then there are mechanisms in R allowing you to make the data available for loading or via lazy-loading. See section 1.1.5 (Data in packages) in the manual [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.pdf). This is the R-way of doing it.

Another option Gabor Grothendieck gave in [this thread](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2009-January/184745.html) on the R mailing list, is to add following line at the top of a script :

```
this.dir <- dirname(parent.frame(2)$ofile)
```

This will give the directory of the file when sourced using `source()`. Gabor calls it a dirty hack, and I agree with him.

On a sidenote, check also following packages for unit testing in R :

- [RUnit](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RUnit/vignettes/RUnit.pdf)
- [svUnit](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/svUnit/index.html)
- [testthat](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/testthat/)

Comment: [svUnit](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/svUnit/index.html) is an alternative to RUnit

Answer (score 1):

If the functions aren't in a package, and sourced from files via `source()` then perhaps source references might provide something to work with. Argument `keep.source = TRUE` is required, and read the [R Journal article by Duncan Murdoch](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2010-2/RJournal_2010-2_Murdoch.pdf)

Here is a quick example:

```
> setwd("./Downloads/")
> source("../foo.R", keep.source=TRUE) ## if options("keep.source") is FALSE
> bar
function(a, b) {
    a + b
}
> body(bar)
{
    a + b
}
attr(,"srcfile")
../foo.R 
attr(,"wholeSrcref")
bar <- function(a, b) {
    a + b
}

> srcref <- attr(body(bar), "srcref")[[1]]
> attr(srcref, "srcfile")
../foo.R
> ls(attr(srcref, "srcfile"))
[1] "Enc"       "encoding"  "filename"  "timestamp" "wd"       
> attr(srcref, "srcfile")$filename
[1] "../foo.R"
> attr(srcref, "srcfile")$wd
[1] "/home/gavin/Downloads"
```

Of course this assumes you don't know where the sourced functions come from to be of any use and yet the functions need to be sourced...

If this is in a package, then you can have data in a `./data` directory or arbitrary directories in `./inst/`. You can use `data()` toload datasets from the former, and `system.file()` for any file in a package. See the relevant help pages.

Answer (score 0):

There's no realistic hope of achieving this in full generality.  Functions don't need to be loaded from files, they can be created dynamically by code, loaded from workspaces and so on.